# What is pro-audio in linux sound architecture?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, jack, pipewire

I learn about pipewire . In some of the articles, I saw pipewire bring together audio, video and pro-audio under Linux . Here what is pro-audio ?

Comment: I think pro-audio designates a set of software dedicated to audio on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipewire's pro audio is a mode of pipewire where direct access to ALSA nodes is granted, making it possible to define properties such as latency and more.
This is made with the professional use in mind, where low-latency is extremely important, studio recordings or other forms of monitoring audio.

To check the current settings of latency use `pw-top` command, to learn more about the nodes use `pw-cli ls Node` or `pw-dump <node-id>`, where the `node-id` can be found with `pw-cli`.

The `QUANT` property of `pw-top` is the current buffer size (latency) of listed node.